# Is there a keyboard shortcut to copy the last message on a slack channel

Tags: slack

Most often my colleagues ping me a command on slack which I would have to copy, for which I will have to select with my mouse and copy.

Does anyone know about any keyboard shortcut to copy the last message on a slack channel? I tried googling it out but no luck.